# C# SSH Connectivity Strange behavior

Tags: c#, ssh

I am stuck with a strange behavior of SSH Connectivity.

I have built a tool (in c#), which uses dotnetssh lilbrary to connect to SSH Server and download the exchange rates. I am using a Back Ground Worker thread to connect sync a CSV price with exchange rates. I have used this code:

## Events:

```
private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
this.bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
this.bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
this.bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(this.bw_DoWork);
this.bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.bw_ProgressChanged);
this.bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

## Connecting SSH

```
this.shell = new SshShell(this.txtServer.Text, this.txtUser.Text);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtPassword.Text))
this.shell.Password = this.txtPassword.Text;
this.shell.LogFilePath = path1; //CSV file path
this.shell.RedirectToConsole();
Console.Write("Connecting...");
this.lblStatus.Text = "Connecting...";
this.bw.CancelAsync();
if (!this.bw.IsBusy)
        this.bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The above code ensures that the csv as specified in Path1, keeps on synced with the exchange rates provided by the server.

Ok it is working fine, CSV is linked with the SSH Server and it keeps on fetching rates. I installed this tool over 20 machines in my office in New Delhi, India and works just fine. But I installed this on two machines on my client in USA and found that the shell is connected, but the CSV is not fetching the prices. I am just unable to guess what may be the reason. Any help?

I thought it might be security issue, then I uninstalled Anti Virus, and then disabled Firewall as well. But still, it doesn't fetch the prices. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Vikas B

Comment: Can you connect via SSH directly (non-programmatically).  I'm wondering if perhaps the server you're trying to connect to is set to only accept connections from a specific geographic region.

Comment: Yes, I can use Putty and still connect to SSH Server. Strange but true.

Comment: Are you able to manually sync/retrieve the CSV when connected via Putty?  If the code hasn't changed, then I'm thinking it has to be something on the server side.